# How to pronounce terminal "-al"

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I'm confused about how to pronounce *-al* at the end of the word.

These words end with *-al* and are pronounced without a "ə" sound.

- dig·it·al */ˈdijitl/*
- men·tal */ˈmentl/*

These words also end with *-al*, but are pronounced with a "ə" sound.

- lo·cal */ˈlōkəl/*
- glob·al */ˈglōbəl/*
- herb·al */ˈ(h)ərbəl/*

Why does the first group not have the "ə" sound, but the second group does?

Comment: Is this about `al` or about all variants ending in `l`? Is it coincidence that all your samples end in `al`?

Comment: My pronunciation may be wrong but I pronounce the second syllable in all five of those words the same way.

Comment: @Joachim: Thank you for your comment. I just changed the title.

Comment: For me, all of these words end with [əl].

Comment: The difference between `/l̩/` and `/əl/` is unclear. Please provide a minimal pair.

Comment: @Random832: I don't believe there any minimal pairs, since these are allophones at the end of a word after a consonant, meaning they are different pronunciations of the same phoneme, and even many Americans pronounce *little* with /əl/. Words like *menial* will always have /əl/ in them, while words like *battle* often are pronunced with just /l̩/.

Comment: It's not even clear to me that there is a sound difference. Isn't it just a different way of writing the same sound? (since "`ə`" in english notation is always "unstressed" rather than a proper mid vowel, the closest thing to the latter is `ʌ`)

Comment: @Random832: You'll have to take that up with the editors of the *Webster's,* *American Heritage,* and *Oxford* dictionaries. Listening to some of these words on forvo.com, I believe I can hear the difference in the two extreme cases (although there are a lot of in-between pronunciations which I'm not entirely sure how to classify).

Comment: @Random832: I just thought of a minimal pair in my speech: *met a lion* versus *metal ion.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For American pronunciation, both the *Oxford* dictionary's American pronunciation and the *American Heritage* dictionary's leave out the /ə/ in words like *little*, *riddle*, *mantle*, *metal* that I think of as ending /təl/ and /dəl/, but not words ending in other consonants followed by /əl/, like /nəl/, /bəl/, /kəl/. *Merriam-Webster* uses /t<sup>ə</sup>l/,  /d<sup>ə</sup>l/ and /n<sup>ə</sup>l/, but uses /əl/ after other consonants; the /<sup>ə</sup>l/ symbolizes the same pronunciation as in *Oxford* and *American Heritage*: the /l/ is the nucleus of its own syllable, which contains no vowel.

For British pronunciation, the *Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary* on-line uses either /l/ and /<sup>ə</sup>l/ for all these words; I think it depends only on the spelling. I believe these are supposed to symbolize the same sound (no schwa). The online global *Oxford* dictionary seems to use /(ə)l/ for all of these words, meaning the schwa is optional. So presumably the schwa is supposedly left out in RP.

Going to forvo.com and listening to the pronunciation of words, it seems that Americans generally (not always) do put the schwa in after consonants other than /t/ and /d/, but many (not all) Americans leave the schwa out after /t/ and /d/. I'm not a linguist, so I can't say for sure, but I believe these variations are allophonic, meaning that English speakers will perceive them as having the same phoneme. If you leave out the schwa after /t/ or /d/, it is likely you are unaware you're doing so. Don't worry about pronouncing this "right"; you should be understood just as well either way. Even if you're trying to lose a foreign accent, judging from the pronunciations on Forvo, the variation in both native British and native American speakers is large enough that I don't think anybody will notice this. For example, I leave out the schwa after /k/ and /g/, but put it in after /n/.

In my comment above, I said there were no minimal pairs for /əl/ and syllabic /l/, because they are allophonic, but I think I was wrong. The way I speak, there are several multi-word minimal pairs; for example, *metal ion* versus *met a lion,* or *mental aberration* versus *meant elaboration.*

Comment: My personal experience is that they _are_ allophonic, as you suggest. You could butcher those vowels pretty badly and still be understood. FWIW, this is one of the differences in accents beween the two places I have lived: Minnesota; Texas. (+1)

Comment: Just a note: the Oxford dictionary gives the pronunciation of *catalyst* as /ˈkat(ə)lɪst/, which is clearly a case of IPA fail on their part. What I assume they mean is: either /ˈkat.əlˌɪst/ or /ˈkat.lˌɪst/. The way they've written it would be naturally read: either /ˈkat.əlˌɪst/ or /ˈkatˌlɪst/.

Comment: Is it intentional that you write [/ɘ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_central_unrounded_vowel) instead of [/ə/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_central_vowel#Mid_central_unrounded_vowel)?

Comment: No, that's a typo. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 7):

There are two [allophones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allophone) of /l/ that occur in English, which may be confusing you.  Let's take the word "local" as an example, since you mention it.

The first /l/ is the "light" allophone [l].  This is fairly short, transitioning straight away to the following vowel, and generally behaving in the brief manner that you would expect of a consonant.

The second /l/ is the "dark" allophone [ɫ].  While this has the same basic mouth shape (the tongue is slightly flatter against the roof of the mouth), it has a considerably longer duration.  In many ways it functions more like a vowel than a consonant, as is particularly obvious with words like "little" where it is, in effect, the final vowel.

All of the words you give have "-al" as an unstressed final syllable, and they all use [ɫ] there.  The vowels in unstressed syllables have a tendency to become a neutral [schwa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) /ə/.  This is a short vowel, and in turn tends to shorten in favour of the following /l/, either disappearing entirely or becoming so short it might as well have disappeared.

Exactly how much the schwa disappears seems to be a personal thing; you make one list, @Kosmonaut pronounces them all with a schwa, I pronounce them all without.  I don't think there is a general rule, because I don't think there is general agreement.

Comment: I don't think the allophones of /l/ are relevant here: for most varieties of English, all these words have 'dark l'. What is at issue is whether syllabic 'l' and 'schwa + l' are different, either phonemically or phonetically.

Comment: Fair point.  I introduced the business of allophones because it's easily overlooked that [ɫ] acts in many ways like a vowel.